# Scaling Worker processes on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was able to scale my Heroku workers by using `heroku ps:scale worker=3` from CLI.

Do I also need to edit my Procfile like `worker: env TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE='*' COUNT='3' bundle exec rake resque:workers` or is this redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `heroku ps:scale worker=3` will spin up 3 dynos each running the `worker` defined in your Procfile.

Your definition of worker is `worker: env TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE='*' COUNT='3' bundle exec rake resque:workers`. This command will create 3 worker threads within a dyno. These worker threads will share the resources of the dyno (memory, cpu).

So if you make both changes then you'll end up with 3 dynos each with 3 worker threads - for a total of 9 workers threads.

Hope that clarifies things. I don't know the needs of your application I'll let you be the judge of that but if your jobs aren't that intensive then you may be able to get by with 1 dyno that has 3 worker threads. You can save some money this way. Goodluck